# How to get Google All url's from Google Chrome using C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome

How I can get All URL's from google chrome. for example If there are two different instance running on my computer and each instance contain multiple URL's. How I can get list of All.Right now I can only get one active URL tab.

```
AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);
AutomationElement elmUrlBar = null;
elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Adresse und Suchleiste"));                          
if (elmUrlBar != null)
  {
    AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
    if (patterns.Length > 0)
        {
            ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);
        }
}
```

is it possible to get All URL's.Source code should be C# compatible. I'm not native English speaker. I did my best to ask question. please don't mark negative.